# Matlab Function weird behavior

Tags: matlab, function, intervals

I have this problem with Matlab(, also i am new to Matlab)

I wrote this function:

```
function pret = p_t(i)

    if (i<=0)
        pret = (1/4)*exp((1/2)*i);
    elseif ((1 <= i))
        if(i <=4)
            pret = (1/9)*(i-1);
        else 
            pret = 0;
        end
    else
        pret = 0;
    end
```

end

so if i run it like this p_t(1:4) i get 0; 0.1111; 0.2222; 0.3333
basicly everytime it hits the part where it is supposed to be zero it gives me all zeros no matter if some "valid" values are in the inteval
eg p_t(-5:5) gives me all zeros

http://puu.sh/kYEyo/6bf0574d34.png This is the function i am trying to program ("sonst" is german for "otherwise" or "else")

any ideas where the problem could be?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: (*Just for the kicks*): You can get the same as an inline function: `x =@(t) ( ~( (t < 1 & t >0) | ( t >4)) ) * (   (0.25*exp(0.5.*t))*(t<=0) + ( (1/9) *(t-1) *( t< 4 & t> 1 )))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong on this but -if- is a binary expression so when used on a vector with anything other than all zeroes it will evaluate true. This code doesn't appear to iterate through the passed vector. I am not certain what the answer is supposed to look like but this iterates through each element of i and stores the answer in pret as another vector.

```
function pret = p_t(i)
    pret=zeros(size(i));
    for j=1:length(i)
        if (i(j)<=0)
            pret(j) = (1/4)*exp((1/2)*i(j));
        elseif ((1 <= i(j)))
            if(i(j) <=4)
                pret(j) = (1/9)*(i(j)-1);
            else 
                pret(j) = 0;
            end
        else
            pret(j) = 0;
        end
    end
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: To give the precise explanation from the documenation: "An expression is true when its result is nonempty and contains only nonzero elements (logical or real numeric)." As soon as one element of the vector does not match the condition, it is evaluated as false.